# How to count two word sequences in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to count two word sequence in a list of words using python. I converted the one word list into a list of two words.I then want to try to count the frequency of all the similar two word lists. I tried the counter function but it gives me an unhashable type: 'list'. An example of my code can be seen below:

```
s = ['one', 'two','three','four','five','six','one','two']

print s
print
p=[]
i=0
for i in range(0,len(s)/2):
    p.append(s[i*2:i*2+2])

print p
wordcounter = Counter(p)
```

I am trying to have the output so that the most occuring two words are displayed at the top with the number of occurances next to them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's d expected output

Comment: for example: {['one two'] 2} {['three four'], 1} {['five six'], 1}

Comment: `one two` can `one three two` this as well?

Comment: no I prefer it to just be the first two "one two" then the next two words "three four" and so on. Thank you.

Comment: @vks, I think the OP is trying to generate n-grams and sort the results.

Comment: Yes i am trying to generate bi-grams, count them and sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter works only with hashable items. Items of `p` are lists, so they are not hashable. One way to go around it, is to joint the inner list of strings, e.g.

```
wordcounter = collections.Counter(" ".join(v) for v in p)
print(wordcounter)
# gives
# Counter({'one two': 2, 'three four': 1, 'five six': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement - "I am trying to have the output so that the most occuring two words are displayed at the top with the number of occurances next to them."

You should try [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method and tell us if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I could do this is a nice one-liner list comp. Turns out its not so nice:

```
newlist=[ii for n,ii in enumerate([[x,[lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(lst),2)].count(x)] for x in [lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(lst),2)]]) if ii not in [[x,[lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(lst),2)].count(x)] for x in [lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(lst),2)]][:n]]
```

please have mercy on my soul